# Jquery dragend events in jquery-dragarrange

Tags: jquery, drag

I'm usin this library:
https://github.com/vishalok12/jquery-dragarrange

I need to run a function when I'm done dragging the item.

```
<div id="elements-container">
  <div class="draggable-element d-1">Drag 1</div>
  <div class="draggable-element d-2">Drag 2</div>
  <div class="draggable-element d-3">Drag 3</div>
  <div class="draggable-element d-4">Drag 4</div>
</div>


$(function () {
    $('.draggable-element').arrangeable();
});


function dragEnd(){
    alert('Drag End');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code there is a `dragEndEvent` property in options.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.draggable-element').arrangeable({
        dragEndEvent: function(){
             alert('Drag End');
        }
    });
});
```

That was a very quick scan through the code for the library you are using, not tested, but please let me know if it works!

UPDATE - just saw the section under "Optional Parameters" on the GitHub. I *think* that the dragEndEvent is not actually a call back but a named event. In other words, it triggers this event by name on drag end. The default is `drag.end.arrangeable`.

Try this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $('.draggable-element').arrangeable({
        dragEndEvent: "dragend"
    });
    $('.draggable-element').on("dragend", function(){
        alert("Drag End");
    });
});
```

Or just using the default, use:

```
$(function () {
    $('.draggable-element').arrangeable();
    $('.draggable-element').on("drag.end.arrangeable", function(){
        alert("Drag End");
    });
});
```

EDIT NUMBER TWO!

Sorry, this is what happens when posting answers without having chance to test code!

The `drag.end.arrangeable` event is triggered on the **parent** element, not the draggables! (I am not sure why the developer did it that way?)

```
$(dragElement).parent().trigger(dragEndEvent, [$(dragElement)]); <<< see - .parent()
```

So the code is:

$(function () {
$('.draggable-element').arrangeable();
$('#elements-container').on("drag.end.arrangeable", function(){
alert("Drag End");
});
});

You should also be able to write the second part as

```
$('.draggable-element').parent().on("drag.end.arrangeable", function(){
    alert("Drag End");
});
```

But I am not sure if this would create multiple bindings. For some reason I am having massive trouble with the internet today and testing things is simply failing. I made this JsFiddle to test : https://jsfiddle.net/jhartnoll/0ys9gbt6/ but it isn't loading properly my end due to my internet, but try it!

Comment: copying literally generates an error on the line:

$(dragElement).parent().trigger(dragEndEvent, [$(dragElement)]);

Comment: I have tried the 2 options and the trigger is not executed. Instead, inserting an alert in the file drag-arrange.js we see that the line is executed.


        $(dragElement).parent().trigger(dragEndEvent, [$(dragElement)]);
        alert("fnDragEnd");

Comment: Updated answer - if you're getting multiple bindings I would use a different library. Either it's me, my connection (not loading the files correctly) or there are some binding issues within that code, but I don't have time to test that!

Comment: thank you very much. for now I modify the library so that it works in my case